# Can someone explain this JavaScript Real-time clock to me?

Tags: javascript, time, clock

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
h=checkTime(h);
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just don't quite understand these two lines:

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
```

Can someone explain this in words? What does getElementById('txt'), innerHTML, and setTimeout('startTime()',500) do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference).

- `getElementById` gets an HTML [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element) with the given ID
- The `innerHTML` property of a DOM element specifies the element's HTML
- The `setTimeout` method runs a function after a specified number of milliseconds
  Note that this code is extremely bad practice; *never* pass a string to `setTimeout`.
  It should be `setTimeout(startTime, 500)`, passing the function itself.
  You can even pass an anonymous function:

  ```
  setTimeout(function() { alert('Five seconds later...'); }, 5000);
  ```

Comment: `<div id='txt'>The Clock</div>`, `document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML` set's the "value" of the div (or whatever it is) to the current time.

Comment: Another bad practice is to use `setTimeout()` as a way to ensure that the DOM is ready. In most cases it will be, but will it **absolutely** be ready after 500ms?

Comment: @Daniel: He isn't.  The function is called by onload; `setTimeout` is used to update the clock.

Comment: @SLaks: Blah you're right. That'll teach me to answer a question before fully reading the code :P.

Comment: Waaait... So what **is** the difference between the string(?) 'startTime()' and startTime?

Comment: @DarkLigkt: The string is a string of code which will be `eval`'ed.  [`eval` is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx), and slow, too.

Comment: The literal `startTime` is a reference to a function, just like any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first line gets the element on the page that has an `id` attribute of `txt` (in this case the `<div>`) and sets the content (innerHTML) to a string with the formatted time.

The second line sets up a timer in JavaScript to call the same function again after 500 milliseconds. In essence the next time to update the clock. **Note** this is every half second. It should probably have a value of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTML, you'll see that there's a `<div id="txt">`. The `getElementById('txt')` method does exactly what it sounds like, it grabs the `<div>` that has the ID `txt`. The `innerHTML` property will get what's inside the `<div>` and will let you change what's in it as well.

`setTimeout()` is a method that allows you to delay the execution of a particular function. It accepts a function and a time in milliseconds. In this case, after 500 milliseconds the `startTime()` function will be called. <strike>My guess is that it's in there to allow the entire DOM tree to load before it runs the function.</strike> I read the code wrong. The `setTimeout()` call is used to recursively call `startTime()` but inserts a 500ms delay so the browser won't freeze trying to run an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML element can be assigned an `id` attribute, that uniquely defines it.

The code

```
document.getElementById('txt')
```

returns a reference to the DOM object that represents some HTML element with the id *txt*.

The `innerHTML` property of that object represents the HTML inside that element. If you assign a string to that property, this string replaces the HTML that used to be there

The `setTimeout` function sets a timeout, such that it will execute a supplied function once the supplied timeout (given in milliseconds) has expire.

In your case

```
 setTimeout('startTime()',500);
```

will execute the function `startTime` in 500 milliseconds.

`setTimeout` returns an identified that you could use to cancel your request at a later time.

You can find more about [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.setTimeout) at MDN or with a bit of judicious Googling (or Binging or Lycosing or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('txt')` tells the browser you want to manipulate the element with an id of "txt" (in this case, an empty div).

The `.innerHTML` part means you simply want to change the HTML inside of the div to a certain value which is specified next.

`setTimeout('startTime()',500)` is used to execute a function after a certain amount of time. The first parameter (`startTime()`) is which function you want to execute, and the second parameter (`500`) means how many milliseconds to wait before executing the function. When the `setTimeout` calls the function that it is in, it means the page will keep looping the function every 500 milliseconds (or whatever number of milliseconds is specified)